# Манипуляции над байтами: как прочитать файл с кириллицей

Tags: python, кодировка, python-3.x, unicode

есть файл `1.txt`с содержимым: `Привет`. Открываю его и получаю байты:

```
b'\xcf\xf0\xe8\xe2\xe5\xf2'
```

но если вместо `Привет` написать `Hello` получается:

```
b'Hello'
```

дальше я могу просто взять эти данные, перевести в строку `b'Hello'.decode("utf-8")` и проводить разные манипуляции над ними(например, зашифровать этот текст и обратно записать)...

но с кириллицей так не сделаешь... при открытии изображения та же картина... подскажите что делать со строками типа `b'\xcf\xf0\...xf2`?

Comment: Можно полный код, где у вас не получается сделать `decode('utf-8')` к кириллице из файла?

Comment: А вот для изображений так делать конечно нельзя, потому что они - это не текст в utf-8 (обычно :), и надо работать с байтами как есть

Comment: `.decode("utf-8")` ожидает, что встроке хранится последовательность байт, которая будет utf-8. Для английской строки это так и есть. А вот для кириллической у Вас там похоже обычный cp1251. "Привет" в utf-8 выглядит так `\xD0\x9F\xD1\x80\xD0\xB8\xD0\xB2\xD0\xB5\xD1\x82`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы прочитать текст, просто откройте файл в текстовом режиме:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    text = file.read()
```

В этом случае `open()` использует `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` кодировку (что-нибудь вроде `cp1251` на русской Винде), чтобы преобразовать байты в текст. Можно явно передать кодировку, используя `encoding` параметр, если кодировка файла может отличаться от кодировки по умолчанию.

`b''` это текстовое представление `bytes` объекта (`repr(obj)`) -- оно совпадает c представлением, используемым в тексте Питона для создания  констант типа `bytes`.

Не ASCII символы запрещены в `bytes` константах, поэтому они задаются с помощью escape-последовательностей таких как `b'\xcf'`.

Не путайте объект `obj` (`type(obj) == bytes`) и его текстовое представление (`type(repr(obj)) == str`).

Answer (score 5):

В случае с таким файлом и с таким содержимым вы можете его открыть с указанием кодировки (я так понимаю, у вас `cp1251`?), а потом делать с ним какие-либо преобразования.

```
text = open("1.txt", 'r', encoding="cp1251").read()
text
>> 'Привет'

text2utf = text.encode('utf-8')
text2utf
>> b'\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'

text2cp1251 = text2utf.decode('utf8')
text2cp1251
>> 'Привет'
```

Возможно, не до конца понял ваш вопрос.