# Кодировка django/pycharm

Tags: python, django, шаблоны, pycharm

Сейчас изучаю django В простеньком проекте без шаблона вполне нормально отображаются данные на русском языке, даты и т.д. Как только подключаешь шаблон - ощущение, что слетает кодировка, хотя все файлы в UTF-8, да и в шаблоне charset установлен тоже в UTF-8

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div style="background-color:grey; margin: 15px auto; weight: 90%; color: #fff">
    <h3>Текущее время: <i>{{ date }}</i></h3></div>
</body>
</html>
```

А вот отображается это просто ужасно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите в чём лажа? может при вызове шаблона нужно дополнительно какие-то параметры передавать?

```html
def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    #html = "<html><body>Сейчас:  %s </body></html>" % now
    fp = open('./templates/dateTmpl.html')
    t = Template(fp.read())
    fp.close();
    html = t.render(Context({'date': now}))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Собственно IDE PyCharm 5.0.1, Django 1.8, Python 3.5.1

Comment: `open()` использует `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`; передай `encoding="utf-8"` явно. См. [Манипуляции над байтами: как прочитать файл с кириллицей](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496565/23044). Вероятно, в Django есть метод, который позволяет по имени шаблон открыть напрямую, не используя `open()`.

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно, помогло.  Локаль на дату не распространилась, но тут уже разберусь. Суть уловил

Comment: @jfs Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: у меня не достаточно знаний по django, чтобы адекватный ответ предоставить (руками открывать шаблоны c помощью `open()` по относительным путям, я считаю не хорошо).

Comment: @jfs но ваш коммент в итоге решил конкретную проблему ТС, независимо от того, какие у вас знания ;)

Comment: использование абсолютных привяжет меня к ФС, а я пишу и тещу на нескольких платформах. проще относительный путь, всё же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> open() использует locale.getpreferredencoding(False); передай
>   encoding="utf-8" явно. См. Манипуляции над байтами: как прочитать файл
>   с кириллицей. Вероятно, в Django есть метод, который позволяет по
>   имени шаблон открыть напрямую, не используя open()

Спасибо за ответ jfs

Answer (score 1):

В django имеется функция `render`. Есть подозрения, что она будет работать как надо:

```
from django.shorcuts import render

def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    context = {'date': now}
    return render(requset, 'dateTmpl.html', context)
```