# Python, проблемы с кириллицей в списках и кортежах

Tags: python, кодировка, python-2.x, кириллица

Есть код :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

hw = 'мир'
print hw
string = []
string.append(hw)
print string
```

После запуска  выдает вот это:

```
мир
['\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80']
```

С кортежами тоже самое, как это исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать юникодные строки: `u'мир'`. То что вам показывает внутри списка - это ваш текст в кодировке utf-8.

Comment: Эффект есть
[u'\u043c\u0438\u0440']

Comment: Вообще, по идее вывод элементов списка должен нормально работать: `print string[0]`, а на вывод `print` от списка не обращать внимание, т.к. к элементам списка применяется `repr`, который делает строки с кириллицей нечитаемыми. Правда, под Windows и такой вывод остается не читаем, т.к. кодировка консоли - cp866 а не utf-8. Зато работает нормально с юникодными строками.

Comment: Linux,  он родимый Ж)

Comment: Тут был коммент про то что когда оно будет передано функции, то функция будет оперировать кракозябрами - нет, "кракозябры" - это то что выводится на экран, потому что `repr` портит вывод, а внутри оно все нормально хранится.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем случае на python2 - никак.

Вы пытаетесь получить строковое представление списка (в вашем случае это аналогично вызову repr). Однако это порождает проблемы так repr возвращает 'str' объект  (на самом деле байтовую строку) которая содержит utf-8 символы этого списка, а когда вы пытаетесь это вывести python конвертирует в кодировку по умолчанию, которая для python 2 - это ascii, соответственно и выводится экранированный юникод.

Можно попробовать выводить так

```
print u'[%s]' % u','.join(unicode(x) for x in [u'привет', u'мир'])
```

В python 3 такой проблемы нет, потому что теперь всё юникод. И кодировка по умолчанию - utf-8. Везде. Поэтому всё работает как вы ожидаете

```
$python3
Python 3.5.1+ (default, Mar 30 2016, 22:46:26) 
>>> print(['привет', 'мир'])
['привет', 'мир']
>>> repr(['привет', 'мир'])
"['привет', 'мир']"
>>> # аналогично
['привет', 'мир'].__str__()
"['привет', 'мир']"
```

Comment: `unicode(x)` здесь либо бесполезен (ввод в примере уже unicode тип имеет) либо вреден: если хотите байты в Юникод превратить, то следует использовать `.decode()` метод c указанием кодировки.

Answer (score 4):

1. **Используйте Unicode вместо байт для работы с текстом в Питоне.** Например, добавьте `from __future__ import unicode_literals`, чтобы строковые константы создавали бы unicode объекты даже без явного `u''` префикса. При [чтении текста из файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496565/23044) используйте `io.open()`, чтобы получить unicode. При получении данных из сети, декодируйте байты в Юникод в соответствии с протоколом, например, если [кодировка указана в Content-Type http заголовке](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14592762/4279):

   ```
   text = data.decode(response.headers.getparam('charset'))
   ```

   См. [ответ, описывающий как получить текст, если данные возвращаются внешним процессом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/497719/23044).
2. Напрямую печатайте списки/кортежи только для отладки, так как в этом случае для каждого элемента `repr()` функция вызывается: чья задача получить однозначное представление объекта, например, `['\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80']` это текстовое представление списка, содержащего байтовую строку. В Питоне 3, вы получили бы `[b'\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80']` (явный `b''` для байтовой константы). См. [Чем отличается `__repr__` от `__str__`?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/534440/23044)

Форматируйте списки/кортежи/другие коллекции явно:

```
>>> print ', '.join([u'мир'])
мир
```

В Питоне 2, `repr()` оставляет как есть только "printing characters" (в С локали это печатаемые ascii символы), для которых `isprint()` возвращает ненулевое значение (такие символы являются текстовым представлением самих себя). Остальные символы экранируются:

```
>>> print([u'мир'])
[u'\u043c\u0438\u0440']
```

На Питоне 3, `str(some_list)` также вызывает `repr()` для элементов списка `some_list`, но при этом *печатаемые в текущем окружении* символы могут быть отображены как есть (`мир`) вместо использования экранирования (`'\u043c\u0438\u0440'`).

Схожие вопросы:

- [Python. Перевести байт-код в человекочитаемый вид в элементе списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/521481/23044)
- [Python string prints as [u'String']](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36891685/4279)