# Python проблема с кодировкой при использовании функции list

Tags: python, кодировка, python-3.x, list, urllib

Я делаю свой первый проект и остановился в одном месте. У меня проблема с кодировкой или, возможно, с чем-то другим.

```
import urllib.request
import re

url = urllib.request.urlopen("http://olx.pl/sport-hobby/rowery/radomsko/?search%5Bdist%5D=30")
page_code = url.read().decode("utf-8")

prices_regex = '<p class="price">(.+?)</p>'
prices_pattern = re.compile(prices_regex)

prices = re.findall(prices_pattern, str(page_code))

for a in prices:
    print(a)
```

Если я напишу так, как выше, то после компиляции не покажет ничего. Если я оставлю только команду `page_code`, то показывает код страницы с верной кодировкой. А если я напишу так:

```
import urllib.request
import re

url = urllib.request.urlopen("http://olx.pl/sport-hobby/rowery/radomsko/?search%5Bdist%5D=30")
page_code = url.read()    

prices_regex = '<p class="price">(.+?)</p>'
prices_pattern = re.compile(prices_regex)

prices = re.findall(prices_pattern, str(page_code))

for a in prices:
    print(a)
```

Покажет то, что я хочу, только в неправильной кодировке. Я думал, что можно написать `decode` после `print`. Но есть ещё одна проблема. Я не знаю как использовать `decode` с функцией  `list`.

Comment: Первый вариант правильный, просто регулярное выражение не матчит текст, находящийся на нескольких строках.

Comment: По поводу последнего предложения - распишите что конкретно вы хотите получить.

Comment: @insolor  По поводу последнего предложение: результат при использовании urllib автоматически преобразуется в тип list.  Я хочу получить только конкретную информацию с сайта (напр. цены). И если я не использую decode в строке с page_code, информация показывается (но не в той кодировке). Но если добавляю decode, то после компиляции результат не показывается вообще. Я просто не знаю при выполнении какой конкретно команды эти данные теряются, либо почему не выводятся.

Comment: Данные не теряются. Например, я сделал `page_code = url.read().decode("utf-8").replace('\n', '')` в вашем первом варианте, и цены начинают выводиться. Как я уже сказал, проблема в том, что регулярное выражение не матчит текст, разбитый на несколько строк. По идее есть настройки `re`, чтобы правильно это отрабатывать без костылей.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Не используйте`str(page_code)`: это либо бесполезно (`bytes.decode` итак возвращает `str`) либо неправильно (если `page_code` `bytes`).

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае проблема в том, что текст, который вы пытаетесь матчить, находится на нескольких строках, например так:

```
                                                <p class="price">
                            <strong>1 600 zł</strong>
                        </p>
```

Чтобы регулярное выражение матчило такой текст, нужно добавить аргумент `re.DOTALL` или `re.S` ([справка](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.S)) при вызове `re.compile`:

```
prices_pattern = re.compile(prices_regex, re.S)
```

Полный вариант кода:

```
import urllib.request
import re

url = urllib.request.urlopen("http://olx.pl/sport-hobby/rowery/radomsko/?search%5Bdist%5D=30")
page_code = url.read().decode("utf-8")

prices_regex = '<p class="price">(.+?)</p>'
prices_pattern = re.compile(prices_regex, re.S)

prices = re.findall(prices_pattern, page_code)

for a in prices:
    print(a.encode("utf-8"))
```

При выводе добавил перекодировку в байты из-за того, что консоль под Windows не хочет отображать польские символы. Результат получается такой:

```
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>4 500 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>650 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>195 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>200 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>100 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>700 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>110 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>55 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>170 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>50 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>600 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>20 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>50 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>299 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>50 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>499 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>250 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>30 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>399 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>800 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>899 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>300 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>4 500 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>40 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>30 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>300 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>50 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>80 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>120 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>100 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>40 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>40 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>50 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>220 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>70 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>50 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>400 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>60 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>80 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>250 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>250 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
b'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<strong>80 z\xc5\x82</strong>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
```

Чтобы выделить только цены с валютой, нужно другое регулярное выражение, например такое:

```
prices_regex = r'<p class="price">.*?(\d[\d\s]*\w+).*?</p>'
```

Пример результата:

```
b'1 199 z\xc5\x82'
b'1 550 z\xc5\x82'
b'650 z\xc5\x82'
b'100 z\xc5\x82'
b'35 z\xc5\x82'
b'370 z\xc5\x82'
b'350 z\xc5\x82'
b'1 200 z\xc5\x82'
b'89 z\xc5\x82'
b'480 z\xc5\x82'
b'25 z\xc5\x82'
b'15 z\xc5\x82'
b'398 z\xc5\x82'
b'39 z\xc5\x82'
b'200 z\xc5\x82'
b'850 z\xc5\x82'
b'999 z\xc5\x82'
b'59 z\xc5\x82'
b'150 z\xc5\x82'
b'50 z\xc5\x82'
b'350 z\xc5\x82'
b'850 z\xc5\x82'
b'55 z\xc5\x82'
b'550 z\xc5\x82'
b'40 z\xc5\x82'
b'11 z\xc5\x82'
b'1 199 z\xc5\x82'
b'900 z\xc5\x82'
b'200 z\xc5\x82'
b'930 z\xc5\x82'
b'385 z\xc5\x82'
b'999 z\xc5\x82'
b'350 z\xc5\x82'
b'90 z\xc5\x82'
b'349 z\xc5\x82'
b'250 z\xc5\x82'
b'399 z\xc5\x82'
b'349 z\xc5\x82'
b'299 z\xc5\x82'
b'550 z\xc5\x82'
b'450 z\xc5\x82'
b'550 z\xc5\x82'
```

Comment: Моя цель - вывод либо только цифр (цен), либо цифр с валютой (в данном случае "zł").

Comment: @PiotrDróżdż, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

При работе с текстом следует использовать Unicode. Но при передачи данных по сети, используются байты, поэтому необходимо сначала декодировать байты в Юникод, используя подходящую кодировку (`unicode_text = some_bytes.decode(encoding)`). В противном случае (если оставить байты как есть) легко получить [кракозябы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044), так как разные части окружения, с которыми взаимодействует ваш скрипт, могут использовать разные кодировки (html может использовать одну кодировку, терминал может использовать другую, [итд](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044)).

[Кодировка может быть указана как в Content-type http заголовке так и самом html-документе (e.g., `<meta charset>`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14592762/4279).

Чтобы извлечь желаемую информацию из html-документа, [можно использовать html-парсер вместо регулярных выражений](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # $ pip install beautifulsoup4

with urlopen(url) as response:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

prices = [p.get_text(strip=True) for p in soup.find_all('p', 'price')]
print(*prices, sep=' | ')
```

#### Output

```
1 199 zł | 899 zł | 850 zł | 5 zł | 330 zł | ...
```

Видно, что `BeautifulSoup` автоматически позаботилась о кодировке (`prices` это список Unicode строк) и удобно эту библиотеку использовать для распознавания html. Таким образом код продолжит работать, если страница поменяет кодировку или слегка изменит разметку—решение с жёстко прописанной кодировкой, использующее регулярные выражения в лучшем случае громко сломается или хуже: молча выдаст искажённые данные.

Если у вас проблемы с отображением списка `prices`, то см. [Python, проблемы с кириллицей в списках и кортежах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538619/23044).
Если у вас есть проблемы с печатью Юникода в консоль, то см. [Как из Python вывести на Windows-консоль строку в Юникоде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/141035)