# Кодировка, Python 2, Jupyter

Tags: python, кодировка, jupyter-notebook

Как побороть кодировку во втором print?

```
dict = {'Мороженое':[{'Тип':'Пломбир', 'Цена':256}, 
                     {'Тип':'Эскимо', 'Цена':221}]}
print dict['Мороженое'][0]['Тип'] 

print dict['Мороженое'][0]
```

Вывод:

Пломбир

{'\xd0\xa2\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbf': '\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80', '\xd0\xa6\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0': 256}

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Как json-данные \u0413\u0440... преобразовать в русский текст](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/606885/23044)

Comment: [Python, проблемы с кириллицей в списках и кортежах](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538619/23044)