# Печать списка с русскими символами выводит : '\xd0', '\xb9',

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, кодировка, utf-8

```
def checkValid(s, message, username):
    patres = re.findall(r"\w+|\d+|[а-яА-Я]", message)
    print(patres)
```

Если вводить английские буквы то всё нормально, но если ввести русские выводит вот такое: '\xd0', '\xb9', '\xd1', '\xd1',
В чём проблема?

Comment: 1- явно упомяните, что Python 2 используете. 2- для текста, используйте Unicode (и для message и для самого регулярного выражения + флаг `re.UNICODE` -- тогда оно упростится: `words = re.findall(ur"\w+", message, flags=re.UNICODE)` 3- если коллекцию печатаете (список здесь), то руками её форматируйте, чтобы текст получить, а не `repr()` для строк. См. [Как вывести в консоль русские символы c выполняемой программы на python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/580971/23044) и [Python, проблемы с кириллицей в списках и кортежах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538619/23044)