# Запись в json файл словаря с юникодом

Tags: python, python-2.x

Пишу парсер с помощью Selenium, из спарсенных значений я составляю список списков, из которого уже формирую словарь.

Из словаря я потом буду составлять JSON.

Проблема в том что при выводе полученного словаря, вместо кириллицы отображается код.
Пример:

```
{u'\u041d\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0440 \u043a\u0432\u0438\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0446\u0438\u0438': u'14210143449', u'\u041a\u043e\u043c\u0438\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f': u'66,98 \u20bd', u'\u0421\u0443\u043c\u043c\u0430 \u043f\u043b\u0430\u0442\u0435\u0436\u0430': u'849 \u20bd', u'\u041d\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0440 \u043a\u0430\u0440\u0442\u044b': u'***************6693', 'name': u'\u041f\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0432\u043e\u0434 \u043d\u0430 \u043a\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0443 Visa ************6693', 'image': u'https://static.qiwi.com/img/providers/logoBig/1963_l.png', u'\u0418\u0442\u043e\u0433\u043e': u'915,98 \u20bd', u'\u0414\u0430\u0442\u0430 \u043f\u043b\u0430\u0442\u0435\u0436\u0430': u'04.11.2018 \u0432 14:30'}
```

Как можно исправить?

Пример кода:

```
result.append(["image", image])
result.append(["image", image])
result.append(["image", image])
product_data_dict = dict(result)
print product_data_dict
```

Comment: это unicode, а чего у вас ключи для словаря одинаковые?

Comment: Для python2 это нормальное поведение, это не ошибка вообще. Тут ничего не нужно исправлять.

Comment: @insolor я хочу сохранить его в txt, в формате Json. Он будет нормально выглядеть?

Comment: Если преобразовывать в json с параметром `ensure_ascii = False`, то нормально.

Comment: @insolor json.dump(json_str, fp, ensure_ascii=False, encoding='utf8'), не помогает

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Python, проблемы с кириллицей в списках и кортежах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538520/python-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%85)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рабочий вариант кода:

```
import json
import io

d = {u'\u041d\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0440 \u043a\u0432\u0438\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0446\u0438\u0438': u'14210143449', u'\u041a\u043e\u043c\u0438\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f': u'66,98 \u20bd', }
with io.open("test.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as fp:
    s = json.dumps(d, ensure_ascii=False)
    fp.write(s)
```

Содержимое файла:

```
{"Номер квитанции": "14210143449", "Комиссия": "66,98 ₽"}
```

Comment: s = json.dump(json_str, ensure_ascii=False)
TypeError: dump() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given). Python 2.7

Comment: @danilshik, dump**s**